# Attempted to load class "XXXBundle" from namespace "Acme\XXXBundle". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Tags: php, error-handling, bundle, symfony4, classnotfoundexception

I have created a reusable bundle and I need to integrate it to a project. Here is my bundle composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Acme\\XXXBundle\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Acme\\XXXBundle\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
}
```

Then, i add it to my project as shown

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../my-xxx-bundle"
    }
]
```

Symfony flex does all the magic. But when I try to execute anything it shows me an error in my project src/Kernel.php:40

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\ClassNotFoundError
Attempted to load class "AcmeXXXBundle" from namespace "Acme\XXXBundle".\n
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in src/Kernel.php
```

My bundle structure is this

[image]

My project bundles.php file looks like this

```
    return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Nelmio\CorsBundle\NelmioCorsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle\TwigExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Acme\XXXBundle\AcmeXXXBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

Also, I share here my Configuration.php class and the extension class, as too my bundle class

```
    class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('smart_ad_server');
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->getRootNode();

        $rootNode
            ->children()
            ->scalarNode('user')->defaultValue('asd')->info('you need to set this parameters!!')->end()
            ->scalarNode('password')->defaultValue('asd')->info('you need to set this parameters!!')->end()
            ->scalarNode('subnet')->defaultValue('asd')->info('you need to set this parameters!!')->end()
            ->scalarNode('url')->defaultValue('asd')->info('you need to set this parameters!!')->end()
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}

    class AcmeXXXExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = $this->getConfiguration($configs, $container);
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $container->setParameter('my-xxx-bundle.user', $config['user']);
        $container->setParameter('my-xxx-bundle.password', $config['password']);
        $container->setParameter('my-xxx-bundle.subnet', $config['subnet']);
        $container->setParameter('my-xxx-bundle.subnet', $config['url']);
```

...

```
        $loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.xml');
    }

    public function getAlias()
    {
        return 'smart_ad_server';
    }
}

    /**
 * AcmeXXXBundle
 */
class AcmeXXXBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getContainerExtension()
    {
        if (null === $this->extension) {
            $this->extension = new AcmeXXXExtension();
        }

        return $this->extension;
    }
}
```

Iḿ using symfony 4.x for both project and bundle.
I have tried with dump-autoload and composer update and nothing. Could anyone help me?

Comment: So, "_did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace_"?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Also, **did** you actually use a `use` statement or not?

Comment: You will need to `use` the `Acme\XXXBundle\AcmeXXXBundle` namespace.